# remove element div that selected

Tags: jquery

i have a problem with jquery `remove()` :

```js
function removeVendor(e){
e.remove("div.jumbotron");
}
```

```html
    <!-- this 1 div -->
<div class="jumbotron in_hanca">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Nama Vendor</label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select name="nama_vendor[]" class="form-control" required="">
          <option value="">--Pilih Vendor--</option>
           
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Jumlah</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah_di_vendor[]" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button onclick="addVendor()" type="button" class="btn_tambah_vendor">add</button>
    <button onclick="removeVendor(this)" type="button" class="btn_kurangi_vendor">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<!-- this 2 div -->
<div class="jumbotron in_hanca">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Nama Vendor</label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select name="nama_vendor[]" class="form-control" required="">
          <option value="">--Pilih Vendor--</option>
           
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Jumlah</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah_di_vendor[]" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button onclick="addVendor()" type="button" class="btn_tambah_vendor">add</button>
    <button onclick="removeVendor(this)" type="button" class="btn_kurangi_vendor">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

if i click the button remove, its just remove button not all of `div.jumbotron` how to fix it ? . **this text dummy for allow code ** "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pharetra tortor nisi, scelerisque vehicula orci accumsan vel. Etiam placerat, velit quis blandit rutrum, sem nisi hendrerit ligula, eget finibus dui velit accumsan ipsum. Donec neque justo, ornare non gravida vitae, condimentum et purus. Mauris vestibulum neque arcu, "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.btn_kurangi_vendor').click(function() {
  //$(this).closest('.jumbotron').css('border','2px solid red');
  $(this).closest('.jumbotron').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron in_hanca">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Nama Vendor</label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select name="nama_vendor[]" class="form-control" required="">
          <option value="">--Pilih Vendor--</option>
           
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Jumlah</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah_di_vendor[]" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button onclick="addVendor()" type="button" class="btn_tambah_vendor">add</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn_kurangi_vendor">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<!-- this 2 div -->
<div class="jumbotron in_hanca">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Nama Vendor</label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select name="nama_vendor[]" class="form-control" required="">
          <option value="">--Pilih Vendor--</option>
           
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Jumlah</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah_di_vendor[]" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button onclick="addVendor()" type="button" class="btn_tambah_vendor">add</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn_kurangi_vendor">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, its work. I have been tried like this , but not working. Now, my problem solved. Thanks guys..

Comment: guys, look again. i have been update the script.. please help me once again

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan this is not how you get help on this site. Edits to other people's answers are strictly for improving their answer. If you have a question you need to ask a new question or edit your current one. This is a misuse of the edit functionality and will get you almost no visibility at all.

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan,  as leigero mentioned , don't edit others answers unless you are improving on them , especially the accepted ones. I had to edit my accepted answer again to make it working because you had left it in non-working state. if I had not done that someone else might have mistaken that to be correct answer (which obviously it would not have been then) and banged his head in frustration for not being able to get it working.

Comment: thanks for telling to me @leigero. im newbe in here and need guidance. but this work and thanks for update code. im sorry for edit, and i dont do it again, :)

Comment: @shariqkhan You approved the edit it seems. So moving forward you may want to reject edits like this on your answers so that you don't have to go back and fix them.

Comment: @leigero Yes i clicked it on it mistakenly. Too many windows pen like Spidy's web. Got entangled :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script

**Javascript** :

```js
function removeThis(elem){
 elem.parentElement.remove()
}
```

```html
<div class='div'>
      some element <button onclick="removeThis(this)">remove element</button>
      </div>
    <div class='div'>
      some element <button onclick="removeThis(this)">remove element</button>
      </div>
    <div class='div'>
      some element <button onclick="removeThis(this)">remove element</button>
      </div>
```

**Jquery** :

```js
$('.div button').click(function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div'>
  some element <button >remove element</button>
  </div>
<div class='div'>
  some element <button >remove element</button>
  </div>
<div class='div'>
  some element <button >remove element</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function removeThis(e) {
            $(e).parent().remove("div.div");            
        }
</script>

<div class='div'>
        some element <button onclick="removeThis(this)">remove element</button>
    </div>                   
    <div class='div'>        
        some element <button onclick="removeThis(this)">remove element</button>
    </div>                   
    <div class='div'>        
        some element <button onclick="removeThis(this)">remove element</button>
    </div>
```